# Best way to calculate total badge count in Javascript?

Tags: support, javascript, badges, jsonp

I'm using Javascript and JSONP and want to find-out a user's total badge-count (i'm not using any libraries).

At first I naively added up the badge counts individually, but some user's have no badges. I also want to make sure it keeps working if the API changes to only list badge types the user has or a platinum badge is added.

I can't iterate through them either and userInfo.badge_counts.length is undefined.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API (once it's version 1.0*, anyway) won't change.  You're concerns are unwarranted.

Just sum the gold, silver, and bronze badges counts you get from `/users/{id}`.

<sub>*And with 0.9 being a release candidate, there almost certainly won't be any changes in *badges* of all things before 1.0</sub>

Comment: I know, but it makes sense (at least to me) to make it easier to upgrade when a new version does appear.

Still, the main problem that prompted this question was that when I do that for some users (such as #999 on SuperUser) that don't have badges, the result I get is "NaN."

Comment: @Simon - those fields are marked as optional.  You'll have to check for presence before summing across them.  There are lots of places in the API where such checks are necessary.